# The product of the Fermi-Dirac distribution and the function of the natural logarithm

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, integration

The generalised Fermi-Dirac integrals can be written as

$$F_n(\eta,\theta)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^n \sqrt{1+(x\theta/2)}dx}{e^{x-\eta}+1} \ .$$

Is there any possibility of rewriting the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty dpp^2\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{E(p)-\mu}{kT}\right)+1}\ln\left(\frac{(k+p)^2}{(k-p)^2}\right) \ ,$$

where k is some non-negative real number, E(p) is the dispersion relation and $\mu$ is the chemical potential, in terms of the generalised Fermi-Dirac integrals? This question comes from the fact that I have a numerical routine which handles only the generalised Fermi-Dirac integrals. Expanding the logarithm in the power series is not a good idea as all terms would have to be included. I was thinking maybe about taking the derivative w.r.t. k to get rid of the logarithm, calculating numerically the derivative for some value of k and then, in the end, performing some integration to come back to the previous function. Is there any way of handling such a problem?

Comment: You may find some useful tools here: "Notes on Fermi-Dirac Integrals" https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0116 . There is not much that you can do analytically.. for numerical methods see e.g. "An accurate method for the generalized Fermi–Dirac integral" https://doi.org/10.1016/S0010-4655(01)00153-9

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?